# LocationListBloc doesnt extend Bloc<dynamic, LocationListState>

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

I am currently refactoring my code to the bloc pattern and have created a bloc for a screen that fetches a list of locations from a json file in assets. The event being the fetch, and the states being initial, loading and loaded.

On my UI screen, I want to use BlocBuilder but when I use the BlocBuilder widget it gives me the error :

**LocationListBloc doesnt extend Bloc** with the LocationListBloc underlined with a line

My code is structured in folders as as follows

- lib/blocs/location_list_bloc
- lib/blocs/location_list_event
- lib/blocs/location_list_state
- lib/blocs/blocs

UI / location_list

location_list_state

```
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import 'package:gt_project_bloc/blocs/blocs.dart';

class Locations extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocBuilder<LocationListBloc, LocationListState>();
  }
}
```

```
import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';
import 'package:gt_project_bloc/models/models.dart';
import 'package:meta/meta.dart';
import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';


abstract class LocationListState extends Equatable {
  const LocationListState();

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}

class LocationListinitial extends LocationListState {}

class LocationListLoading extends LocationListState {}

class LocationListLoaded extends LocationListState {
  final List<SavedStations> locationlist;

  LocationListLoaded(this.locationlist) : assert(locationlist != null);
}
```

location_list_event

```
import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';

abstract class LocationListEvent extends Equatable {
  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}

class Fetch extends LocationListEvent {}
```

location_list_state

```
import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';
import 'package:gt_project_bloc/models/models.dart';
import 'package:meta/meta.dart';
import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';


abstract class LocationListState extends Equatable {
  const LocationListState();

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}

class LocationListinitial extends LocationListState {}

class LocationListLoading extends LocationListState {}

class LocationListLoaded extends LocationListState {
  final List<SavedStations> locationlist;

  LocationListLoaded(this.locationlist) : assert(locationlist != null);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found my issue, i had a stateful widget on the same page called LocationList and it was confusing its state LocationListState with the same name of my blocs state

Comment: This actually happened to me, spent hours trying to debug until I found this, Due to the naming conventions, this could be a common source of error